# how can i get back vold.fstab ,i accidently deleted it due to usbox was not responding after i edited it,plz help

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

i had rooted my phone-sony xperia e c(1504) and then edited vold.fstab but then after i saved it the us box stopped responding so i deleted the file unknowingly .after that storage access is lost ,only phone memory is working ,how can i remount my internal Sd and ext sd card by any method which is having a stable output.

Comment: what do you mean by us box ?

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the the vold.fatab file of the same phone model to someone who has it. Then copy the file to your /system/etc/ and set the correct permissions.